# How can I change my username in Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Everytime I try to join a server it states that I have an invalid name. This is because I have a space in my Xbox gamertag.

Is there a way to change my Minecraft name without changing my Xbox gamertag?

As you can see, it is locked:

[image: Minecraft name setting]

[image: Minecraft error]

Comment: Before you lynch me: Yes, I know that I'm an idiot for choosing a username with a space.

Comment: I'd almost be tempted to report it as a bug to Mojang

Comment: @JonK I'm already spamming Microsoft with bug reports (edge is buggy). Microsoft Connect doesn't have bug report function for Minecraft, where can I report this "bug"?

Comment: It seems that the MCPE JIRA site also serves as the Windows 10 beta JIRA site, so [here](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE). Assuming that it's a valid XBox username (it let you pick it so I'm assuming it is) then surely it's not unreasonable to expect it to work with your games

Comment: @JonK reported both to JIRA and Xbox.

Comment: I just tried joining the "Lifeboat SG" server (address= "sg.lbsg.net") and I get the invalid username just like you.  My xbox tag has a space too.

Comment: You can change your gamer tag (once for free, but obviously it changes it everywhere on xbox live), that's the only solution so far I think.  Also, setting up a second gamer tag is the only way you can get it to run on two computers due to xbox live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I will try to keep this answer up to date (let me know if any info no longer applies).

Minecraft Windows 10 edition uses the Xbox gamertag as your name.  This cannot currently be changed.

The **[bug is known](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-11045)** by the developers.  Remember, the game is still in beta so a fix is very likely in the near future.  The bug also has consequences for the pocket edition as you can see in the link.  You will also get the same message when joining servers with people already using that name.

More to the question.  Right now, you cannot change your name.  You would think that you can change your gamertag, but unfortunately **[another bug exists](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-10825)** whereby changes to the gamertag are not synchronised to your settings.  Remember that switching your gamertag costs money (although you can change the initial randomly generated tag given to you free of charge).

Comment: I reported this to Xbox support too, they requested a picture of the error, I sent them that but since then they didn't return back to me.