# Can I change my Xbox Live gamertag without an Xbox?

Tags: xbox-network

As I stated in this question: [How can I change my username in Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/244339/how-can-i-change-my-username-in-minecraft-windows-10-edition) I have some issues joining some servers, so I want to change either my Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition Username (it looks like it isn't possible at the moment) or my Xbox Live Gamertag (looks as a better choice to me).

Can I change my Xbox Live Gamertag thru web or by the Windows 10 app? (I know that it is paid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be changed through the [official Microsoft Xbox website](https://account.xbox.com/en-US/changegamertag).

Following this link, you can sign in, check your desired gametag for availability, and proceed in changing your tag.

Comment: and some random guy already has ardaozkal. great.

Comment: Could you tell us where the link is heading and possibly provide any other information? While i dont classify this as a link only answer, i expect others might

Comment: @Timelord64 It is a link in the Xbox website. I found out that we can change it thru there.